# Parsing error with big json files on Firefox

Tags: json, parsing, firefox

My web application loads in parallel few big json files (> 90Mo) from a server.
These big json files have valid structure.
Each times the application loads these big files with Firefox (v44.0.2 for Windows), we get random parsing errors on one of them :

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unterminated string at line 4233392 column 290 of the JSON data
```

With Chrome we don't have any problem.

I recreate a light example to reproduce the problem, see https://jsfiddle.net/asicfr/bvmfv4ea/.
So i have a very small html page which loads the same json file with 4 ajax parallel requests.
I reproduce the same problem, with an apache or nodejs server.

I searched the internet but I have not found a similar problem.
From what I read on the internet, there is no limit size to download json files.

Is anybody have any idea ?